# Creating a new AVD with lower release version

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I wanted to change my minSDKversion from 10 to 7 of my android app. So I read that I should changen my Manifest to include:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

I wanted to test this with the emulator running release 7 of course. But when I went to create a new AVD, there were no targets for that release. So, I went to the Android sdk manager and selected Android 2.1 (which is release 7). When trying to install this, I got this error:

```
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3 File not found: /home/dorien/bin/android-sdk-linux/temp/android-2.1_r03-linux.zip (Permission denied)
```

I changed the permissions to this folder for me to 755. When I looked closer, I noticed that /temp/ was empty? How do I fix this? Reinstall android plugin?

Also, when I exported the project, it gave me the following error:

```
Conversion for Dalvik format failed. Unable to execute .dex: wrapper was not properly loaded.
```

I guess this is again due to the release 7 not being installed? I read in forums that I should restart eclipse, but to no avail. Any suggestions as to my next move?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in Windows not in Linux, But the only thing you need to know is about permissions, If you can give read and write permission for this directory then it will be fine.

Comment: Did that already, as explained in the question, the folder is just empty.

Comment: Ok, I got it. The folder was empty because the file could not be deleted. Ok, monday morning effect... My permissions were: 
--edit--

For the record, these are my permissions:

drwxr-xr-x  12 dorien users 4096 Nov 19 12:12 android-sdk-linux

drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root  4096 Jul 31 12:29 temp

SOlution: chown dorien temp/

Answer (score 0):

you just copy the androidsdk folder to another folder the go to 
windows -> preference -> android-> change the sdk location